# Android socketio causing phone to get hot

Tags: android, socket.io

We are building an Android app that uses socketio, via Gottox, which is causing the phone to overheat. We tried a branched version of the Gottox that was suppose to fix this heat related bug, but the app and socketio connection would crash when moving from wifi to cell coverage.

Anyone have this same issue? Or where to look?